# Load text only (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, meteor

On my project, I have this line of code for a preview of a content within the post item.

```
<div style="content-preview"><p>{{{content}}}</p></div>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to add a Template.someTemplate.rendered script to load only the text within the {{{content}}}. Also, if there was a way to strip away the html tags...

Thank you!

Comment: When you say "load only the text within the {{content}}", what do you mean? What don't you want to load? And you are speaking about the html tags Meteor automatically puts up?

Comment: Add the template helper code.

Comment: @Kyli There is a lot of coding. Basically I am inserting content through summernote in Meteor. The content is then inserted into the database in html strings. When I call {{{content}}}, the content is rendered back into html. But I want to load the content in a preview box before going into the actual page with content. For example, the page content could include images, embedded videos, and etc. I don't want to load any of that in the preview. I just want the text, and the text limit to what it will show.

Comment: @Rajanand02 I don't have any for it yet.... {{{content}}} is a basically a string of html codes inputted from a wysiwyg editor.